# How many CPUS on my CentOS 7?

Tags: cpu, centos

I have a Java program which runs quite fast on my local Mac and its info as below:

```
Processor:2.4 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9
Memory: 16 GB 2400 MHz DDR4
```

When I run the same program on a CentOs 7, it seems slower. It has 115G memory. The CPU is below. Is that because a single core's performance is not as good as my mac?

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1199.902
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 20
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme ...

bogomips    : 4389.73
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1199.902
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 20
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme ...

bogomips    : 4389.73
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1199.902
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 20
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 4
initial apicid  : 4
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4389.73
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1278.454
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 20
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 6
initial apicid  : 6
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4389.73
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 4
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1299.536
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 20
core id     : 4
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 8
initial apicid  : 8
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4389.73
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 5
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1266.906
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 20
core id     : 8
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 16
initial apicid  : 16
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4389.73
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 6
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 2095.397
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 20
core id     : 9
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 18
initial apicid  : 18
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4389.73
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 7
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 2399.938
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 20
core id     : 10
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 20
initial apicid  : 20
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4389.73
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 8
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 2399.938
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 20
core id     : 11
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 22
initial apicid  : 22
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4389.73
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 9
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1199.768
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 20
core id     : 12
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 24
initial apicid  : 24
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4389.73
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 10
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1199.902
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 20
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 32
initial apicid  : 32
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4395.55
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 11
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1199.768
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 20
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 34
initial apicid  : 34
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4395.55
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 12
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1199.902
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 20
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 36
initial apicid  : 36
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4395.55
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 13
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1199.902
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 20
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 38
initial apicid  : 38
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4395.55
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 14
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1200.439
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 20
core id     : 4
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 40
initial apicid  : 40
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4395.55
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 15
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1199.902
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 20
core id     : 8
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 48
initial apicid  : 48
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4395.55
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 16
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1199.902
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 20
core id     : 9
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 50
initial apicid  : 50
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4395.55
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 17
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1200.036
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 20
core id     : 10
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 52
initial apicid  : 52
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4395.55
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 18
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1200.036
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 20
core id     : 11
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 54
initial apicid  : 54
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4395.55
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 19
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1200.439
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 20
core id     : 12
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 56
initial apicid  : 56
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4395.55
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 20
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1205.407
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 20
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4389.73
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 21
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1200.170
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 20
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 3
initial apicid  : 3
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4389.73
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 22
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1309.875
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 20
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 5
initial apicid  : 5
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4389.73
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 23
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1199.902
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 20
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 7
initial apicid  : 7
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4389.73
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 24
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1260.192
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 20
core id     : 4
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 9
initial apicid  : 9
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4389.73
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 25
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1200.170
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 20
core id     : 8
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 17
initial apicid  : 17
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4389.73
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 26
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 2399.938
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 20
core id     : 9
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 19
initial apicid  : 19
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4389.73
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 27
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 2399.938
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 20
core id     : 10
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 21
initial apicid  : 21
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4389.73
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 28
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1305.175
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 20
core id     : 11
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 23
initial apicid  : 23
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4389.73
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 29
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1620.324
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 20
core id     : 12
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 25
initial apicid  : 25
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4389.73
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 30
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1200.170
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 20
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 33
initial apicid  : 33
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4395.55
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 31
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1199.902
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 20
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 35
initial apicid  : 35
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4395.55
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 32
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1210.644
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 20
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 37
initial apicid  : 37
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4395.55
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 33
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1201.647
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 20
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 39
initial apicid  : 39
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4395.55
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 34
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1199.768
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 20
core id     : 4
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 41
initial apicid  : 41
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4395.55
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 35
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1200.036
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 20
core id     : 8
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 49
initial apicid  : 49
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4395.55
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 36
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1211.450
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 20
core id     : 9
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 51
initial apicid  : 51
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4395.55
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 37
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1205.273
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 20
core id     : 10
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 53
initial apicid  : 53
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4395.55
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 38
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1273.217
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 20
core id     : 11
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 55
initial apicid  : 55
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4395.55
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 39
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xb000021
cpu MHz     : 1199.902
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 20
core id     : 12
cpu cores   : 10
apicid      : 57
initial apicid  : 57
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : ...

bogomips    : 4395.55
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: It's likely that your local machine can do single-threaded operations faster. That said, it's impossible to tell you the reason why with certainty without knowing what the code does and how it's written.

Comment: you may want to consider the differences in java runtime implementation between the two systems as well. Most of the time, CPU is not the most meaningful performance bottleneck unless you are working with specific types of applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its impossible to say, with certainty.  There are far more factors in how fast a program runs than just the CPU.

That being said, the CPU in your CentOS box is almost a decade old.  Your Core i9, you didnt mention the model, is probably much newer.  Generally, newer CPUs, even at the same frequency, will have more speed optimizations and run faster.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/92981/intel-xeon-processor-e5-2630-v4-25m-cache-2-20-ghz.html your system has 10 cores and 20 threads.

It has a base frequency of 2.2ghz burstable to 3.1ghz

You have not specified the exact model of CPU in your Mac but its likely it has a faster turbo speed, possibly 4.8ghz/combined with a lower tdp one can speculate that it is is significantly faster for non parellelised loads.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance I noted that one's **unfair contest** because you want to compare two processors of **different generations**.

The best way to measure the real processing power's by **benchmark** apps like **[Phornix Test Suite](https://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/)**.

Benchmarks are perfect they **don't lie** because measure the hardware potencial by **pure maths, stats and algorithms**.

In case of Linux a kernel **well recompiled** can do all difference **in some cases**.